# Remove unity, back to gnome and desktop crash

Tags: 10.10, unity

I installed unity packages from the software center, and after that some promblems started at the normal desktop session.

I unistalled the unity packages and now in desktop session, compiz crashes, indicators crash...

I need help to reinstall the desktop session normally.

How i reinstall the ubuntu 10.10 desktop clean whitout format?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Someone else "may" have issue with this, but you could see if this make a difference.

mv ~/.config ~/.config.org and
mv ~/.gconf ~/.gconfig.org

logout| in.

NOTE: This WILL reset all your gnome panels!

If you don't get any better, just mv them back.

mv ~/.config.org ~/.config
mv ~/.gconf.org ~/gconf

Logout| in.

Comment: it works but not at all. i also find how eo reinstall indicators, with synaptic i installed "indicator-applet-complete".

But i still have the problem to activate compiz.